# Bluetooth Trancievers for arduinos

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-nano, hardware

Would it be possible to use to of [these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Bluetooth-Serial-Transceiver-Module-Base-Board-clear-button-For-Arduino-SWTG-/231608470902?hash=item35ecf0cd76) on two separate arduino's, to send and receive information? I am having difficulties understanding the chinese-english descriptions and haven't seen any documentation on doing this. There would be no phone involved. There would only be two arduino's with a Bluetooth module on each of them sending and receiving data from each other.

Answer (score 2):

The boards in your link look funny.  Typical boards like this include the "bluetooth circuit" which piggy-backs onto that board, and is soldered at all those little pads.

Have a look at say, the HC-05 board ~  https://www.google.com.au/search?q=hc05+bluetooth+module&tbm=isch

It's easy to see the part that's missing from the one in your link.

For these HC-05 boards, it's possible to pair two together.  They need to be configured as "Master" and "Slave" though.  Some bluetooth boards can do slave-mode only, so be careful before you purchase.

Comment: To add to this old thread, HC-05 is not the same as HC-06.  HC-06 is a "slave only" model, like @Kingsley mentioned.